# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined (Kinetic js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to make a game where multiple circle objects are made by use of kineticjs.

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--<canvas id="canvasRegn" width="600" height="450" style="margin:100px;"></canvas>-->
        <div id="container" style="width: auto; height: auto; background:#000; margin:auto; float:left;"></div>
        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/kinetic-v5.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/rain2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My logic in js is->
I push "enemy" (circular kineticjs objects) into the array "enemyArmada" which is done in the function "createEnemy()".

The the "draw" function is called every 35ms using a setInterval,where the required position and speed are altered to create the moving effect.

Here's the js code:

```
  var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var noOfEnemies = 2;
var enemyArmada = new Array();

createEnemy();

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    listening: true
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    listening: true
});

function createEnemy() {
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfEnemies; i++) {
        var enemy = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: Math.random() * 1200,
            y: Math.random() * 5,
            radius: 6,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
            speed: 3 + Math.random() * 5
        });
        enemyArmada.push(enemy);
    }
//    setInterval(draw, 35);
    draw();
}


function draw() {
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfEnemies; i++)
    {
        console.log(enemyArmada[i].getPosition().x);
        enemyArmada[i].setPosition({x:enemyArmada[i].getPosition().x + 10, y:enemyArmada[i].getPosition().y + 10});
            console.log(enemyArmada[i].getPosition().x + "  " + enemyArmada[i].getPosition().y + "" + enemyArmada[i].speed);
       }
     layer.add(enemyArmada);
    layer.draw();
    stage.add(layer);
}
```

Here's the css:

```
html {
    color:#000;
    background:#222222;
}
a {
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style: none;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
html, body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, code, form, fieldset, legend, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container {
    background:#000;
    margin:auto;
    cursor:none;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

My ultimate aim is to create enemies like in this game:
http://www.sinuousgame.com/

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/R3p5s/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `createEnemy` before the layer object is created, so the variable `layer` value is undefined when `createEnemy` is called..

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    listening: true
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    listening: true
});

//need to call it after the layer is created
createEnemy();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jfGL6/)

You also may want to read about [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

Comment: The error seems to have been removed,thnx.
But the red enemy objects aint moving... any idea why?



Edit:Nevermind... i got it :)
Thanx :)

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK `setInterval()` was commented out? - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jfGL6/2/

Comment: Yeh,i just did it.. thnx :)